# Change server mail from postfix to sendmail virtualmin

Tags: postfix, sendmail, virtualmin

Hi I have already install an ubuntu server with postfix and sendmail mail servers.Although postfix runs perfectly when I go to Virtualmin panel>Virtual Configuration>And choose sendmail mail server to configure >save and rebuild configuration file I get this :
The Read User Mail module is not setup to use the Sendmail mail server. Either adjust its module configuration to match, or change the Virtualmin configuration.
I do not know what to do.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

At first Virtualmin runs perfectly with Postfix. So long you did not setup an external mail server, it is better to keep Postfix with all the other mail services SpamAssasin, Procmail and ClamAV.

To jump over the Read User Mail issue, you have to deactivate it following:

Virtualmin -> System Settings -> Server Template -> Default Template -> Administrators Webmin module and there you can deactivate this feature.

This is only appending for new mail users.

Now Sendmail jumps over this step, but probably you are facing new ones ;-).

Virtualmin is thought to run on every server the mail service. This is very well done together with Postfix. So long you don't have a good reason to change that, I recommend not to switch to Sendmail.

Good luck ;-)
Urs

Ps.
More about Read User Mail and already running mail users:

[Solution to deactivate existing mail users](https://www.virtualmin.com/comment/732490#comment-732490)